Construct map of punctured $n$-sphere like stereographic projection?
If $p$ is the north pole $(0,0,\dots,0,1)$ of the Euclidean $n$-sphere $S^n$, then stereographic projection gives a homeomorphism $\pi_{p}$ from $S^n \setminus \{p\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
How might one directly construct a similar kind of homeomorphism $\pi_{q}$, for an arbitrary point $q$ in $S^n$, of $S^n \setminus \{q\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ — and do it without invoking rotations of $S^n$ and without using known facts about orthogonal transformations?
I tried $\pi_{q}(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x \cdot q} g\left[\left( x - (x \cdot q) q \right)\right]$, where $g(y) = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n)$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, that is, $g$ is the vertical projection of the hyperplane $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : y_{n+1} = 0\}$. Is that correct?
Related: Prove n-sphere is homogeneous without constructing orthogonal transformations?

Wikipedia has you covered.

@BenSteffan: I don't think so: in the section "Generalizations," of the Wikipedia article you cite, it is allegedly is going to produce such a stereographic-like projection for arbitrary $q$, but in doing so suddenly $q$ is actually the north pole again!

Ah, you're right; I apologize. Still, the idea is there: You map $p$ to the intersection point of the line through $q$ and $p$ with whatever hyperplane you're projecting onto (for this to work $q$ needs to not be contained in that hyperplane).

If (as context suggests) the goal is to project to the "standard" equatorial hyperplane $y_{n+1}=0$ using straight lines through $q$, you can't (unless $q$ is the north or south pole) because a lot of lines through $q$ are parallel to the target hyperplane. If that's a problem, are there conditions that can be relaxed?

@AndrewD.Hwang: of course, my mistake: should not project to the equatorial hyperplane, but to a hyperplane through the center of the sphere that is orthogonal to $q$.

@AndrewD.Hwang: and then to complete the story: must exhibit an explicit homeomorphism $g$ of that hyperplane with $\mathbb{R}^n$ -- so that one may verify that the composition $g \circ \pi_q$ has a continuous inverse, where $\pi_q$ is the projection of the punctured $n$-sphere (punctured at $q$).

The formula in the original post (before the edits) is what I would have written. Admittedly, that mapping takes values in the ambient space $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$, though the image is the hyperplane orthogonal to $q$. <> I'm not completely clear on the avoidance of "ambient" Euclidean geometry, however, nor on the Cartesian coordinates $y_i$. The "last" coordinate $y_{n+1}$ is the dot product with $q$, but to my eye existence of the others looks like rotating/using orthogonal transformations on "standard" Cartesian coordinates.

@AndrewD.Hwang: this is for elementary expository purposes, where the audience need not have any background in the orthogonal group, and I want to avoid as much prior experience with linear algebra as possible.

The map $$x \mapsto \frac{x - (x\cdot q)q}{1- x\cdot q}$$
projects $S^n \setminus \{q \}$ homeomorphically onto the orthogonal complement of $q$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, i.e. the linear subspace $L_q = \{ y \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid y \cdot q = 0 \}$. See Stereographic projection when the "North/South Pole" is not given by $(0,...,\pm 1)$? and Tangent bundle of a sphere $T\mathbb S^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^n \times \mathbb S^n - \Delta$.
There are various ways to identify $L_q$ with $\mathbb R^n$.
If $L_q$ is not perpendicular to $\mathbb R^n \times \{0\}$, then we can use your projection $g : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R^n$ (which omits the last coordinate). It restricts to a linear isomorphism $g_q : L_q \to \mathbb R^n$.
If $L_q$ is perpendicular (which means that $q_{n+1} = 0$, i.e. q lies on the equator of $S^n$), then $g$ does not help us. Instead we can omit another coordinate.
